# Join keys in key-value pair list with close value c#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of key-value pairs of <string, int>. I want to merge and construct a new string with  the keys that has close values (+3-3) and add each new string to a list.

Here are the keys and values of my list:
Luger: 9
Burger: 9
Le: 21
Pigeon: 21
Burger: 21
Hamburger: 25
Double: 30
Animal: 31
Style: 31
The: 43
Original: 43
Burger: 44

Here's the output that i want to achieve:

Luger Burger
Le Pigeon Burger
Hamburger
Double Animal Style
The Original Burger

To achieve this, firstly i created a list containing this key-value pairs. And iterate through each item and tried to find close values, assign them to new key-value pairs and delete that index. But that doesn't work properly. That's the code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordslist.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < wordslist.Count; j++)
    {
        if (wordslist[i].Value <= wordslist[j].Value + 3 && wordslist[i].Value >= wordslist[j].Value - 3)
        {

            wordslist.Add(

                    new KeyValuePair<string, int>(wordslist[i].Key + " " + wordslist[j].Key, wordslist[i].Value)

                    );


            wordslist.RemoveAt(j);

        }
    }
    wordslist.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

this doesn't work and produce repetitive results as below:

Pigeon: 21
Style: 30
Burger: 30
Double Double Animal: 30
Burger Burger: 31
Original Original The The Original Burger Original Burger: 42

Is there any algorithm that can iterate through these items and construct a string by merging the keys that has close values and add each item to a list?

Comment: Please show the data in the appropriate structure so that it can be run with the code you've given, a [mre]. Then people would have an easier time helping you get the correct output, without having to transcribe a picture of text.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'm a little unexperienced here, trying to learn the dynamics of stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this logic:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPlusOrMinus3(Dictionary<string, int> fullList, int checkNumber)
{
    return fullList.Where(w => checkNumber <= w.Value + 3 
          && checkNumber >= w.Value - 3)
    .Select(s => $"{s.Key}: {s.Value}" );
}
```

The string format isn't perfect for you, but the logic should hold.

And in use you could do something like:

```
var forOne = GetPlusOrMinus3(values, 1);
var resultString = String.Join(", ", forOne);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Which would write out:

> one: 1, two: 2, four: 4

And to loop through everything:

```
foreach(var entryValue in values.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", GetPlusOrMinus3(values, entryValue)));      
}
```

Or to loop through anything without resusing any results:

```
var matchedNumbers = new List<int>();
foreach(var entryValue in values.Values)
{
    var matchResults = values.Where(w => entryValue <= w.Value + 3 && entryValue >= w.Value - 3
        && !matchedNumbers.Contains(w.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            
    if (matchResults.Any())
    {
        matchedNumbers.AddRange(matchResults.Select(s => s.Value).ToList());
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",
           GetPlusOrMinus3(matchResults, entryValue)));     
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
one: 1, two: 2, four: 4  
twelve: 12, 10: 10, eleven: 11
six: 6
```

Comment: I changed "GetPlusOrMinus3" method's input to a list of key-value pairs and that worked like charm. Thank you !
`
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in wordslist)
{ var resultvalue = GetPlusOrMinus3(wordslist, kvp.Value);
var resultString = String.Join(" ", resultvalue);
                        safetextlist.Add(resultString);

                    }

                    safetextlist=safetextlist.Distinct().ToList();

                    foreach (var item in safetextlist)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n" + item);
                    }`